# Cant see new repository after git subtree split

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I have a project which uses a few self made "modules". I want to put these modules in separate (read only) repositories. I tried to do this with the `subtree split` command. But I don't see my new branched repository anywhere.

I first ran this command:

```
git subtree split --prefix=src/Modules/Infra --branch=infra --annotate='Infra folder split' --rejoin master
```

Then with the Github GUI client (I'm on Windows) I synced the changes that where pending.

But I don't see any difference. Shouldn't there be a new Repository in my Github account named `infra`? That's what I'm trying to accomplish with this... Is there anything else I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running only that command will not create a new project in Github, it will only create a separate tree of commits in which your `--prefix` directory is the root instead of a subdirectory.

Running that command will output a hash that is the last commit of the new split tree. That is the commit that can be pushed into a new project in Github, but you have to manually create the new project.

```
# First create a new empty Github project

# In your original repository add it as a remote
git remote add subtree_repo path/to/github/repo

# push the split commit hash into the new project as master
git push subtree_repo subtree_hash:master
```

If you no longer have the hash, check the commit that was created by the `git subtree split` command. Since you used `--rejoin` a commit was created that merged the split tree into your `master` branch. One of the parents of that commit is the split tree you want.

Some extra [subtree documentation](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt).